# tomcat: deploying a webapp which is accessed via browser without context root name

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, web-deployment, contextroot

(Sorry for my english, please correct if somethings are wrong).

I have a webapp (spring mvc 4 application) which code is placed in `tomcat-7/webapp/mywebapp/` folder. Webapp is accessed via browser with url `http://my-web-app.loc:8080` (i.e. without context root name `mywebapp` after port number). I have following setups in `tomcat-7/conf/server.xml`:

```
<Host name="my-web-app.loc" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Context path="" docBase="mywebapp" reloadable="true" allowLinking="true" antiJARLocking="true" copyXML="true" />
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
           directory="logs" 
           prefix="mywebapp.access." 
           suffix=".log" 
           pattern="common" 
           resolveHosts="true" />
</Host>
```

I delploy webapp by placing war-file into `/webapp` folder. But after war-file is unpacked and webapp is successfully deployed, I can access to webapp only with `http://my-web-app.loc:8080/mywebapp` url. Url `http://my-web-app.loc:8080` directs me to 404 tomcat error page.

What I have to setup to access to webapp with `http://my-web-app.loc:8080` url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-name the directory from `mywebapp` to `ROOT` (case matters, even on a case-insensitive filesystem).

Also, don't put your `<Context>` element in `server.xml`. Instead, put it into your web application under `META-INF/context.xml`.